# How to record user webcam?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

When the Record Button is clicked the Webcam starts but when you click the stop button nothing happens

I Have this right now but I am not sure if it is recording? How do i know if its recording and how can i re display the recorded video?

```
<html>
<input type="button" value="Record" onclick="record(this)">
<input type="button" value="Stop" onclick="stop(this)">
<video autoplay></video>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">



var record = function(button) {
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.webkitGetUserMedia 
|| navigator.getUserMedia;

window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true}, function(stream) {
  var video = document.querySelector('video');
  video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
  stream.record();
  //setTimeout(stop, 10);
}, function(e) {
  console.log(e);
  //setTimeout(10);
});
};

var stop = function(button){
//alert('Checking');
stream.stop();
stream.getRecordedData(function(blob) {
alert('Checking');
//upload blobusing XHR2.
});
};


</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `stop` function, there is no variable `stream` in scope.  The object that you called `stream.record()` on above was a parameter to the anonymous function back there, and is now inaccessible.

Happily you can easily resolve this problem - simply "save" the reference to a top level variable, something like this:

```
var currentStream = null;

var record = function(button) {
    ...
    stream.record();
    currentStream = stream;
    ..
}

var stop = function(button) {
    currentStream.stop(); // TODO disable stop button if this is null, etc.
    ...
}
```

By the way, when you're working with Javascript you should definitely pay attention to the error console in whatever browser you're using.  You almost certainly would have seen an error like "stream is null or not an object [line 28]", which tells you what the problem is there and then.

Comment: I'm getting these errors i used chrome inspect element console and i got                                              Uncaught TypeError: Object #<LocalMediaStream> has no method 'record' 
(anonymous function) 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'stop' of null 
stop
onclick

Comment: @AlexanderNazarkin Ah, there you are then, that tells you your problem.  The `LocalMediaStream` you're getting back doesn't have a `record` method.